# Selected Value from spinner into new activity

Tags: android, spinner

I'm developing a Androidapplication and I want to be able to start an activity through a spinner value the user have selected.

As an example: In the main activity you'll see a spinner with the values "Color", "Animals". If you choose "Color" and click on a button called "Proceed", you will come to an activity that list different colors in a listview, but if you choose "Animal" from the spinner, you will come to the same activity, but this time it shows a listview of animals instead.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to do this?

(PS this is an example on how I want it to work, I actually need to call everything from a Web Service)

Comment: All the process is on the proceed button. Just check the spinner value in the onClick() of the proceed button and start new activity based on the value of the spinner.

Comment: You can pass the value (animal (or)color) to the next acitivity. Based on that value you can populate values in the listview

Comment: I got an activity called "List" with the default values of "Value 1, Value 2 " and so on. Can't I just overwrite this with the values of colors/animals?

Comment: can you please post code whatever you done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest Solution would be for example:

```
    Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
    String value = yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("ANIMAL")){

     Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, yourNextActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("VALUE", value);
     startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Then in that Activity that You want to start:

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();

     String value= intent.getStringExtra("VALUE");

     if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("ANIMAL")){

      //start the part with animals

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and override the method

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,   long id) 
    {
       // Call the following method to get the selected value of the spinner and perform your 

       //task to start your desired activity
   String selectedValue=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
       if(selectedValue.equals("Colors"))
       {
         //do your task using color
       }
       else if(selectedValue.equals("Animal"))
       {
         //do your task using animal
       }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
     {
    //Do Nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple just use bundle and send the appropriate data to your next activity. A small sample would look like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String spinnerText = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("selection",spinnerText);
        }
    });
```

Then in your next activity get the sent text and manipulate accordingly.